# Recursive definition of binary Strings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

I am have a bit of trouble on how I can provide a recursive definition for all binary strings that represent a number divisible by 4. I know that for such definitions you need a basis step and a recursion step. I know for a fact that a number is divisible by 4 if and only if the last 2 digits are even and they can be divided evenly by 4. I tried taking a stab at it and thought for the basis step all I can provide is something like

Basis Step: $\alpha$ is a binary string

Recursive Step: If $\beta$ $\in$ S .......

How could I represent that what I know about being divisible by 4 to finish this definition off??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any binary number divisible by $4_{10}$ ends in $...100$.  So just recursively pre-pend any binary digits in front of that.

$\alpha 100 \to \beta \alpha 100$ for $\beta \in \{ 0, 1 \}^k$.

Done!

Comment: What does the k stand for?

Comment: $k$ stands for an integer, and $\{ 0, 1 \}^k$ means any string of $0$s and $1$s of length $k$.